# NGINX/FPM Fastcgi Variables to specific Files

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Why it's not possible to set `fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;` to work ONLY for 1 file like:

```
if ($uri ~* /test.php) {
  fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
}
```

Nginx says  `[emerg] "fastcgi_ignore_client_abort" directive is not allowed here`

In general how i can write specific fastcgi variables to work only on specific files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and efficient solution is to use the `include` directive to pull identical configuration directives into more than one location block. For example:

```
location = /test.php {
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
    include common_fastcgi.conf;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include common_fastcgi.conf;
}
```